# PostgreSQL - Query on hstore - column does not exists

Tags: postgresql, hstore

I wonder if someone could have an idea what is going wrong with this simple query on a `hstore` column in PostgreSQL 9.2

The queries are runned in pgAdmin

```
select attributeValue->"CODE_MUN" from shapefile_feature
```

returns: « attributevalue » column does not exists

when doing:

```
select * from shapefile_feature;
```

all the columns are returned including attributeValue, the hstore column

what is the problem?

Comment: I have found the solution, curiously I need absolutely to write the query with those quotes: select `"attributeValue"->'CODE_MUN' from shapefile_feature;`

Comment: PostgreSQL folds identifiers (such as table and column names) to lower case by default, hence the `attributevalue` in the error message. You created the column in mixed case by double quoting it when the table was created, once you do that you have to double quote the column name forever in order to match the case. This is why lower case identifiers with underscores is the standard practice with PostgreSQL.

Comment: @mu is too short wow, I am new to postgres, thank you for that great tip!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PostgreSQL distinguish between "identifiers" and 'literal'. Identifiers are schema, table, column's, .. names, literals are others. A attribute in hstore are not SQL identifiers. So you have to pass their names as literals. Operator "->" is only shortcut for function "fetchval(hstore, text)" with possibility be indexed.

```
select attributeValue->'CODE_MUN' from shapefile_feature
```

is internally transformed to (don't do this transformation by self!)

```
select fetchval(attributeValue, 'CODE_MUN') from shapefile_feature
```

on buggy example in transformed form, you can better understand to error message:

```
select fetchval(attributeValue, "CODE_MUN") from shapefile_feature
```

PostgreSQL tries to find column "CODE_MUN" in shapefile_feature, bacause used double quotes means identifiers (in case sensitive notation).